# How to allow compiler to deduce correct return type for templated get function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a bunch of structs, all with a few elements:

```
struct myExample
{
    std::string elem0;
    int elem1;
};
```

If I could get the following to work, I could avoid a lot of coding.
Write a templated get method which takes the index as a template parameter and returns elem from the struct above.

```
template<int idx, typename K, typename T> T get(const K&) 
{ 
    throw std::runtime_error("should not happen");
}
template<> std::string get<0, myExample, std::string>(const myExample& k)
{
    return k.elem0;
}
template<> int get<1, myExample, int>(const myExample& k)
{
    return k.elem1;
}
```

Here is the main function for the example:

```
int main() 
{
    myExample test;
    test.elem0 = "hello world";
    test.elem1 = 42;

    // does not work:
    //std::string get0 = ::get<0>(test);
    //int get1 = ::get<1>(test);

    // does not work either:
    //std::string get0 = ::get<0, myExample>(test);
    //int get1 = ::get<1, myExample>(test);

    // works:
    std::string get0 = ::get<0, myExample, std::string>(test);
    int get1 = ::get<1, myExample, int>(test);

    std::cout<<get0<<":"<<get1<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to use `::get<0>(test)`, but for some reason the compiler complains that there is *no matching function for call to ‘get(myExample&)’*
even though at least templated function which throws the error should be available, right?

In principle it should be possible to tell the compiler the correct return type, because the type of elem0 and elem1 is defined at compile time.

How can I extend this tuple-like struct to return the correct type without having to write it out manually?

So far this works with older C++ versions, which is the reason I am not supposed to us auto and the like. Is there a way to get this to work without C++11?

[Please check out the example on ideone](https://ideone.com/ZdXFVY).

Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to recreate the functionality provided by [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: @RSahu Though `std::tuple` lacks field names.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I'll let the OP clarify but it's not clear whether the names of the fields are important to them.

Comment: Please demonstrate a [mcve] that doesn't work and demonstrates your problem.  People are *guessing* what you mean (maybe accurately, maybe not) because your question does not contain a [mcve].

Comment: @Yakk I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use template function specialization, it is almost always a bad idea.

Instead use overloading and forwarding.

```
template<int idx>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<int, idx>;

// compile time error if it doesn't match
template<int i, class K>
void special_get(index_t<i>, const K&) = delete;

template<int idx, typename K> 
decltype(special_get( index_t<idx>{}, std::declval<K const&>() ) )
get(const K& k) { 
  return special_get( index_t<idx>{}, k );
}
```

no specializations.

```
inline std::string special_get(index_t<0>, const myExample& k) {
  return k.elem0;
}
inline int special_get(index_t<1>, const myExample& k) {
  return k.elem1;
}
```

these are overloads of `special_get`.  Which one is picked is picked by overload resolution, not template specialization.

Specialization of template functions should not be your first, second or third choice to solve any problem.

Comment: I think you meant to use a variable `k` where `std::declval<K const&>()` was used in the return statement of `get(K const&)`.

Comment: @0x499 yes, and another typo.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler has to deduce all template parameters before considering specializations, and it has no way to deduce `T` this way.

Just remove `typename T` parameter altogether, it's not needed.

---

You might also want to consider a much easier alternative:

```
template <int Index, typename T> auto get(const T &object)
{
    return std::get<Index>(std::tie(object.elem0, object.elem1, object.elem2));
}
```

Comment: For some weird reason I am not supposed to use auto in any of the department's code...

Comment: @Beginner: Then some template metaprogramming techniques are impossible for you to do in C++

Comment: If I remove T I have to put down a return type, but there is not one return type. How can I remove the T parameter from the get function and avoid using auto?

Comment: @AndyG isn't there a way to do this without auto?

Comment: @Beginner IMHO this case warrants an exception. `auto` can be misused in many ways, but this is not one of them. If you have to, replace it with what SirGuy suggested below (if trailing return types aren't allowed, replace `object` in that line with `std::declval<T&>()`).

Comment: @Beginner: There is, but it is much more longwinded. You'll have to write type traits.

Comment: You could probably replace `auto` with `tuple_element_t<Index, decltype(std::tie(object.elem0, object.elem1, object.elem2))>` instead as a trailing return type

Comment: @Beginner You don't have to put down the return type or anything. Just remove the `T` parameter.

Comment: @SirGuy Let's hope trailing return type is not considered a use of `auto`. ._.

Comment: You don't have to use auto, yet it is much easier with it. Try using some of `std::result_of` and so on to get the return type manually. Yet, it is quite cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a little typo that may be confusing the compiler trying to solve the template. In these two lines:

```
template<> int get<2, myExample, int>(const myExample& k) { return k.elem1_; }
template<> boost::gregorian::date get<2, myExample, boost::gregorian::date>(const myExample& k) { return k.elem2_; }
```

you have the same index for both templates, 2. I think you meant 1 for the int specialization.

So I guess that in some scenarios for index 2, the compiler is unable to decide between the int and the date.

Comment: thanks, fixed. I also added an example implementation.